# Multiple Stripe custom elements to paymentintents with handleCardPayment

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I already tried and stripe returns error when I add multiple stripe elements. Its working when you send one card element with elements.create('card') but it doensn't work when I made custom elements and send it to handleCardPayment. Is there a way to send multiple stripe custom elements to handleCardPayment method like in the code below?

```
await this.stripe.handleCardPayment(
      clientSecret, this.cardNumber, this.cardExp, this.cardCvc, {
        source_data: {
          owner: { name: cardholderName.value }
        }
      }
    )
```

Comment: You only need to pass one, so pass your `cardNumber` and it should pick up the others automatically

Comment: Yes but for example I want to make custom elements and make paymentintent with it.

Comment: Yes, that's fine! When using separate Elements for card, expiration, cvc, you only need to pass one of these to your `handleCardPayment` --- they are all part of the same `elements` instance and the other fields should be picked up automatically.

Comment: Thanks bud, that works. I read the documentation and there was no text that states that pass one element will take all of them ... thanks a lot